# Acquire formatted text from fscanf

Tags: c, file, date, logging, scanf

I'm new in C and I need to get specific information from a text file. The text file format is:

```
2015-01-01 12:00:01 rossi S
2015-01-02 12:00:01 bianchi F
2015-01-02 12:00:20 bianchi F
2015-01-03 00:00:01 rossi S
2015-01-03 11:12:20 verdi F
```

This is the struct declaration

```
struct login_attempt{
        int day, month, year, hour, minute, second;
        char username[10];
        char status;
    }; struct login_attempt attempts[256];
```

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
FILE *log_file = fopen("/Users/williambertarello/Desktop/Test/Test/log.txt", "r+");
    if(log_file == NULL){
        printf("\n No selected file \n");
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < total_login_attempts(log_file); i += 1){
            int year =0;
            int month = 0;
            int day = 0;
            int hour = 0;
            int minute = 0;
            int second = 0;
            char username[10];
            char status;

            int ret = fscanf(log_file, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d %s %c", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, username, &status);
            if(ret == 2){
                attempts[i].year = year;
                attempts[i].month = month;
                attempts[i].day = day;
                attempts[i].hour = hour;
                attempts[i].minute = minute;
                attempts[i].second = second;
                attempts[i].status = status;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(log_file);
```

The purpose of this program should be to reveal potential security risk for unattended repeated login failures in a server.

EDIT:
After some suggestions about the if(ret==2) that was uncorrect, I tried this but it's doesn't work either because the variable values from debugging are:

```
for(int i = 0; i < total; i += 1){
            int ret = fscanf(log_file, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d %s %c", &attempts[i].year, &attempts[i].month, &attempts[i].day, &attempts[i].hour, &attempts[i].minute, &attempts[i].second, attempts[i].username, &attempts[i].status);
        }

Login attempt 0 -> {
  day: 1265508352
  month: 32767
  year: -256879960
  hour: 32767
  minute: 1512161226
  second: 0
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` returns the number of matched tokens, in your case a successful scan would match 8, not 2.

Comment: Why does code use `2` in `if(ret == 2)`?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you check the return value of `fscanf` aginst `2`? You are reading more than two parameters, and you would expect to get `8` successful assignments?